# vb script for login ctrl alt del

Tags: vb6, vbscript, windows-xp

When you start your system and see message press `CTRL ALT DEL`. after that normally you see security warning and you have to press `OK`. What I like to do is write a vb script which automatically press `OK` for me.

Can someone please let me know if its possible to write a script which will click on `OK`.

I can't disable `CTRL ALT DEL` on system as this is control by GPO.

Comment: In theory, you cannot - starting from oldest Windows NT they (Microsoft) have specifically noted that Ctrl+Alt+Del logon is designed to avoid any automatic logon bypass. In practice I don't know, what workarounds are possible :)

Comment: I read it some where it is possible but I can't remeber where. I through it was but i might be worng.

Comment: @hello I have to do exactly the same thing when on my work PC, the time you will spend writing a script does not out-weigh simply pressing 'OK'. Furthermore, even with a script you may run into user privilege errors whilst trying to run it. Save your time and leave this one alone : )

Answer (score 1):

You cannot accomplish this with scripting. However, I believe there is a registry trick you can do to accomplish what you desire.

Check out http://www.velikan.net/automatic-login-windows-account.